# system restore stuck on initializing

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-update, system-restore

my pc run into an update and after update is finished, office 365 was deleted from my pc, I tried system restore, but the pc is stuck on system restore initializing, what should I do now, can I force shut down the pc ?

Comment: How long have you let it do it's thing?

Comment: If it stucks for several hours, the computer can only be forced to shut down.